Car Model Making from STL/STEP "Just Surfaces" File - Modification
I'm new on this platform; I'd like to start to create a customized car model, by 3D printing process.
I have purchased a 3D model from a popular website the car is a Ford Escort.
I have received different 3d model file format (UV/STL/STEP;IGES);
The next step is create a 3d body without internal part: I need only the external surface of the car body.
The aim is to create the file STL for the 3D printing process.
I have many problems to manage the surfaces and trasnform them in "only 1 body".
I'm using SolidWorks but I cannot manage the surfaces to join them and create just one body.
You can see the model (downloaded) on the attached images.
If I open the STL file with Blender, I can see the best quality of the car.
What could be the fastest method?
Can I use a specific software?


Sorry but this is not a tutorial site. If you have a specific problem with an operation using Blender we would be able to help, but it sounds as if you need a full workflow tutorial which is off-topic for this site.
